# Dropdown List event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a web form in which i have droped 6 dropdownlists and each dropdownlist have previous seven dates to open files from a specific folder concatenated with date at the end of file name.Problem is that when i select first dropdown list it opens file fine but when i select a date from anyother dropdownlist to open file then it open the same file which was opened from the first dropdownlist.Please see the code and make correction in it.

My Code is Bellow

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Security
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Diagnostics.Process
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Console
Partial Class DashBoard
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub DD1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DD1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Response.Redirect("Reports/Daily Production and Stock Report (Crescent Ujala)/Daily Production and Stock Report (Crescent Ujala) " & DD1.SelectedValue & ".xls")
    End Sub
    Protected Sub DD2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DD2.SelectedIndexChanged
        Response.Redirect("Reports/Daily Production Efficiency Report (Crescent Ujala)/Daily Production Efficiency Report (Crescent Ujala) " & DD2.SelectedItem.Value.ToString & ".pdf")
    End Sub
    Protected Sub DD3_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DD3.SelectedIndexChanged
        Response.Redirect("Reports/September Sowing Report/September Sowing Report " & DD3.SelectedItem.Value.ToString & ".ods")
    End Sub
    Protected Sub DD4_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DD4.SelectedIndexChanged
        Response.Redirect("Reports/September Sowing Report Area-1/September Sowing Report Area-1 " & DD4.SelectedItem.Value.ToString & ".ods")
    End Sub
    Protected Sub DD5_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dd5.SelectedIndexChanged
        Response.Redirect("Reports/September Sowing Report Area-2/September Sowing Report Area-2 " & dd5.SelectedItem.Value.ToString & ".ods")
    End Sub
    Protected Sub DD6_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DD6.SelectedIndexChanged
        Response.Redirect("Reports/Daily P & L Cost sheet/Daily P & L Cost sheet. " & DD6.SelectedValue & ".xls")
    End Sub
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Add Values to Dropdownlist 1
        DD1.Items.Add(New ListItem("", ""))
        DD1.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD1.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -2, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -2, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD1.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -3, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -3, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD1.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -4, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -4, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD1.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -5, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -5, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD1.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -6, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -6, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD1.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        'Add Values to Dropdownlist 2

        DD2.Items.Add(New ListItem("", ""))
        DD2.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD2.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -2, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -2, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD2.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -3, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -3, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD2.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -4, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -4, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD2.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -5, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -5, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD2.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -6, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -6, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD2.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        'Add Values to Dropdownlist 3

        DD3.Items.Add(New ListItem("", ""))
        DD3.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD3.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -2, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -2, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD3.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -3, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -3, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD3.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -4, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -4, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD3.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -5, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -5, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD3.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -6, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -6, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD3.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        'Add Values to Dropdownlist 4

        DD4.Items.Add(New ListItem("", ""))
        DD4.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD4.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -2, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -2, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD4.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -3, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -3, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD4.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -4, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -4, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD4.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -5, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -5, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD4.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -6, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -6, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD4.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        'Add Values to Dropdownlist 5

        dd5.Items.Add(New ListItem("", ""))
        dd5.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        dd5.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -2, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -2, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        dd5.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -3, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -3, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        dd5.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -4, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -4, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        dd5.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -5, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -5, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        dd5.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -6, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -6, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        dd5.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        'Add Values to Dropdownlist 6
        DD6.Items.Add(New ListItem("", ""))
        DD6.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD6.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -2, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -2, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD6.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -3, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -3, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD6.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -4, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -4, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD6.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -5, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -5, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD6.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -6, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -6, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))
        DD6.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Now), "dd MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Now), "yyyy.MM.dd")))


    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Its due to your cache will store the details, so always it will open the same one. For every time refresh/clear your caches so solve this problem.

Comment: Dear there exist another problem too.When i select the last dropdownlist it opens file fine and also when i slect any othere dd its also open the file fine but when first i open the first dd and then if open any other it opens the same file which opened from first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked to make sure that the `OnChange` events for the other dropdown lists are referencing the correct methods in your code? They might all be referencing `DD1_SelectedIndexChanged`.

Incidentally, you really should think about refactoring some of your code as you have a *lot* of repetition there. The list population code should really be moved into the `On_Init` event too.

Comment: That wasn't the complete solution, just a suggestion on how to improve your code. Did you check the events are defined correctly?

Comment: Code is before you check it and tell me where is the incorrection

Answer (score 0):

Put your logic of binding of DropdownList in IsPostaback, as per below

if Not page.ispostback

//then Bind

end if

Comment: I have done it alredy but all in vain plz tell me another solution